# Span and Two Way Containment

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am proving : If $v_1, . . . , v_m$ and $w_1, . . . , w_n$ are vectors in V , then
$Span(v_1, . . . , v_m)$ + $Span(w_1, . . . , w_n)$ = $Span(v_1, . . . , v_m, w_1, . . . , w_n).$ 
I am trying to prove this by showing that $Span(v_1, . . . , v_m)$ + $Span(w_1, . . . , w_n)$ ⊆ $Span(v_1, . . . , v_m, w_1, . . . , w_n)$ and $Span(v_1, . . . , v_m, w_1, . . . , w_n)$ ⊆ $Span(v_1, . . . , v_m)$ + $Span(w_1, . . . , w_n)$. Is this the correct approach?
If it is, then what I continued was 
$Span(v_1, . . . , v_m)$ + $Span(w_1, . . . , w_n)$ = $(a_1v_1+...+a_mv_m)$+$(b_1w_1+...+b_mw_n)$=
$((a_1v_1+b_1w_1)$+...+$(a_mv_m+b_mw_n))$=$(a_1v_1+...+a_mv_m+...+b_1w_1+...+b_mw_n)$=$Span(v_1, . . . , v_m, w_1, . . . , w_n)$. I did a similar arguement the second way. Is this correct? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please use mathjax to format your math. Also, please explain what the $a_i$ and $b_i$ are.

Comment: Proving both containments is always a valid approach if you want to show that two sets are equal.

Comment: @ViktorGlombik Thank you! Wanted to make sure since I never got my assignment back. Ah you're right, I didn't specify $a_i$ and $b_i$. They're constants in my field, F

Answer (score 1):

Let $z\in Span(v_1, \ldots, v_m)$+$Span(w_1, \ldots, w_n)$ then $z=x+y$ for some $x\in Span(v_1, \ldots, v_m)$ and $y\in Span(w_1, \ldots, w_n)\Rightarrow$

$x=a_1v_1+ \ldots+ a_mv_m),\, y=b_1w_1+ \ldots+b_nw_n$ for some $a_i,b_j\Rightarrow$

$z=a_1v_1+ \ldots+ a_mv_m+b_1w_1+ \ldots+b_nw_n\Rightarrow z\in $

Could you continue?